# Prevent EF 5 from generating a property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, serialization, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF5 database first with partial classes. There's a property in my partial class which contains n object which is stored as a column in my database containing XML data. I want to handle the serialization/deserialization of this object when the EF tries to read/write it with a custom getter/setter.

Is it possible to expose the column in my partial class and map it using the EF, without auto-generating a property for it?

ie:

```
public SomeObject BigComplexObject { get; set; } // forms etc in my app use this
public string BigComplexObjectString // when the EF tries to read/write the column, my custom getter/setter kicks in
{
    get { return this.BigComplexObject.ToXmlString(); }
    set { this.BigComplexObject  = new BigComplexObject(value); }
}
```

At present, the EF is auto-generating a member for the column so I'm left with two.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the logic. Leave EF generated property that will be populated with XML string from the database:

```
public string BigComplexObjectString { get; set; }
```

Then do the following:

```
[NotMapped]
public SomeObject BigComplexObject
{
    get { return new SomeObject(this.BigComplexObjectString); }
    set { this.BigComplexObjectString = value.ToXmlString(); }
}
```

Don't forget to add [NotMapped] to instruct EF to ignore this property.

Comment: BigComplexObjectString will be in auto-generated partial class. You can put BigComplexObject property in your own partial class (with same name of course). I've changed the logic in your getters/setters so that EF can map directly and your custom property should not interfere with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we use a little trick for a quite similar case...

We use the property panel (in the edmx file) of our... properties and add something in the "documentation" (summary or long description) line (probably not the best place, but anyway). This can be access by your T4 file.

So you could write something like "useXml" in the property panel, then modify your tt to generate the desired code when (example to get the info in the .tt file)

```
if (edmProperty.Documentation != null && edmProperty.Documentation.Summary = "useXml")
  //generate something special
```

It would be great to have a better place for "cusom infos" in the edmx, but we didn't find anything better for instant.